# How to integrate django app with tcp server

Tags: django, python-asyncio

Is there a way to connect django and a tcp server built with asyncio?

I have a TCP server that should maintain long-lasting connections with clients, but I want to integrate it with Django so that a user can send data over the TCP server based on forms from Django

- I've heard of celery, but I do not know if it would be suitable for this application
- My current idea is to put a temporary tcp client in the django code that receives posts, and have it send data to the tcp server. I would prefer not to do this because I would have to add more special cases to the TCP server in order to recognize that data is being sent from Django and not one of its other clients

Comment: Check [Django Channels](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Also, remember there are standards like websockets for long lasting connections, if you can use them.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not sure if Django Channels is well suited to this problem since it's aimed at websockets. Using websockets to communicate between the TCP server and the Django server would introduce another level of complexity. Repurposing django channels to use TCP also seems complex

Comment: im pretty sure Tornado do that for you, im not 100% sure

Comment: @DiegoVinícius, I've seen that option, however the TCP server is already created in asyncio and makes use of some asyncio functionality that does not seem to exist in Tornado

Comment: You use your django forms and propagate the request (in your views) you call your TCP server, so that way anytime you get a new form request your TCP server will receive it... nothing built-in comes to my mind right now

Comment: @jjmontes that sounds like something that might work... definitely introduces a lot of new parts. There's no need to scale this, it's for controlling devices on a film set

Comment: Maybe try [Quart](https://github.com/pgjones/quart), which will listen for HTTP connections on asyncio. You'll still need to bridge requests to Django. In an experiment, I load Django, call `get_internal_wsgi_application()`, and then call `get_response` on the handler. I still have to manually build a WSGIRequest manually and my implementation is very flawed, so I'm unsure this is a reasonable path to go.

Comment: Here I have uploaded an excerpt of my experiment using asyncio-quart-django-http: https://gist.github.com/jjmontesl/203ac28b6690fb70de67818cb4d6f149 in case it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [aiohttp-wsgi](https://github.com/etianen/aiohttp-wsgi). It offers a WSGI bridge for `asyncio`, on top of [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_quickstart.html), so you can process Django requests within your asyncio process.

Note that, when using Django as a web framework, the model instances lifecycle is usually not a problem because objects live only as long as the view that creates them. When using Django as a service (outside Django HTTP Requests) this doesn't happen, and you need to synchronize access to model instances carefully. This involves avoiding usage of cached/older instances to do modifications, and refreshing model objects anytime other process (ie Django views, or other service code) might have changed them. Django CRM does not guarantee uniqueness of model objects that represent the same database record.

Comment: I don't know why this was down voted, it seems like a workable solution. I'm going to give this problem a bit longer though, because nothing has come up that seems like a clean fix. For now I put the TCP client in the post handler, but I think I'll migrate to this if nothing else comes up